# Ranking ETF values in table in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to programming and am simply trying to add some visuals to my chart, so I apologise if my question is dumb...

I've attempted to create a sector relative strength table in pine and was now wondering if it's possible to rank these sectors automatically in the table? Either in ascending/descending order or that a number from 1-11 is assigned next to the sector according to how strong it is.

I'll attach a screenshot and hopefully what I'm asking is clear.

[image: Rank]

Apologies for the messy code below, I haven't removed lines that aren't being used and like I said, I'm a complete beginner.
Code of my current table:

```
indicator("Sector Relative Strength", overlay = true)

// Main logic

var _t = table.new (position.middle_left, 2, 12, frame_width = 5, border_width = 1)
var _t1 = table.new (position.bottom_right, 5, 2, frame_width = 2, border_width = 2)

// 6 month % momentum

lastMonthmomo = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", close)
sixMonthsclosemomo = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", close [26])
diffM6momo = sixMonthsclosemomo - lastMonthmomo
indTextM6momo = "M6: " + str.tostring((lastMonthmomo - sixMonthsclosemomo)/sixMonthsclosemomo *100, format.percent)

// 12 months % momentum
twelveMonthsclosemomo = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", close [52])
diffM12momo = twelveMonthsclosemomo - lastMonthmomo
indTextM12momo = "M12: " + str.tostring((lastMonthmomo - twelveMonthsclosemomo)/twelveMonthsclosemomo *100, format.percent)

// XLP %
XLPlastMonth = request.security("XLP", "W", close)
twelveMonthsclose = request.security("XLP", "W", close [52])
diffM12 = twelveMonthsclose - XLPlastMonth
XLPindTextM12 = "XLP M12: " + str.tostring((XLPlastMonth - twelveMonthsclose)/twelveMonthsclose * 100, format.percent)

// XLB %
XLBlastMonth = request.security("XLB", "W", close)
XLBtwelveMonthsclose = request.security("XLB", "W", close [52])
XLBdiffM12 = XLBtwelveMonthsclose - XLBlastMonth
XLBindTextM12 = "XLB M12: " + str.tostring((XLBlastMonth - XLBtwelveMonthsclose)/XLBtwelveMonthsclose * 100, format.percent)

// XLE %
XLElastMonth = request.security("XLE", "W", close)
XLEtwelveMonthsclose = request.security("XLE", "W", close [52])
XLEdiffM12 = XLEtwelveMonthsclose - XLElastMonth
XLEindTextM12 = "XLE M12: " + str.tostring((XLElastMonth - XLEtwelveMonthsclose)/XLEtwelveMonthsclose * 100, format.percent)
 
// XLU %
XLUlastMonth = request.security("XLU", "W", close)
XLUtwelveMonthsclose = request.security("XLU", "W", close [52])
XLUdiffM12 = XLUtwelveMonthsclose - XLUlastMonth
XLUindTextM12 = "XLU M12: " + str.tostring((XLUlastMonth - XLUtwelveMonthsclose)/XLUtwelveMonthsclose * 100, format.percent)

// XLF %
XLFlastMonth = request.security("XLF", "W", close)
XLFtwelveMonthsclose = request.security("XLF", "W", close [52])
XLFdiffM12 = XLFtwelveMonthsclose - XLFlastMonth
XLFindTextM12 = "XLF M12: " + str.tostring((XLFlastMonth - XLFtwelveMonthsclose)/XLFtwelveMonthsclose * 100, format.percent)

// XLI %
XLIlastMonth = request.security("XLI", "W", close)
XLItwelveMonthsclose = request.security("XLI", "W", close [52])
XLIdiffM12 = XLItwelveMonthsclose - XLIlastMonth
XLIindTextM12 = "XLI M12: " + str.tostring((XLIlastMonth - XLItwelveMonthsclose)/XLItwelveMonthsclose * 100, format.percent)

// XLK %
XLKlastMonth = request.security("XLK", "W", close)
XLKtwelveMonthsclose = request.security("XLK", "W", close [52])
XLKdiffM12 = XLKtwelveMonthsclose - XLKlastMonth
XLKindTextM12 = "XLK M12: " + str.tostring((XLKlastMonth - XLKtwelveMonthsclose)/XLKtwelveMonthsclose * 100, format.percent)

// XLV %
XLVlastMonth = request.security("XLV", "W", close)
XLVtwelveMonthsclose = request.security("XLV", "W", close [52])
XLVdiffM12 = XLVtwelveMonthsclose - XLVlastMonth
XLVindTextM12 = "XLV M12: " + str.tostring((XLVlastMonth - XLVtwelveMonthsclose)/XLVtwelveMonthsclose * 100, format.percent)

// XLY %
XLYlastMonth = request.security("XLY", "W", close)
XLYtwelveMonthsclose = request.security("XLY", "W", close [52])
XLYdiffM12 = XLYtwelveMonthsclose - XLYlastMonth
XLYindTextM12 = "XLY M12: " + str.tostring((XLYlastMonth - XLYtwelveMonthsclose)/XLYtwelveMonthsclose * 100, format.percent)

// XLRE %
XLRElastMonth = request.security("XLRE", "W", close)
XLREtwelveMonthsclose = request.security("XLRE", "W", close [52])
XLREdiffM12 = XLREtwelveMonthsclose - XLRElastMonth
XLREindTextM12 = "XLRE M12: " + str.tostring((XLRElastMonth - XLREtwelveMonthsclose)/XLREtwelveMonthsclose * 100, format.percent)

// XLC %
XLClastMonth = request.security("XLC", "W", close)
XLCtwelveMonthsclose = request.security("XLC", "W", close [52])
XLCdiffM12 = XLCtwelveMonthsclose - XLClastMonth
XLCindTextM12 = "XLC M12: " + str.tostring((XLClastMonth - XLCtwelveMonthsclose)/XLCtwelveMonthsclose * 100, format.percent)

// Plot % change
table.cell(_t, 1, 0, XLPindTextM12, text_color = diffM12 > 0 ? color.red : color.green, text_size = size.small)
table.cell(_t, 1, 1, XLBindTextM12, text_color = XLBdiffM12 > 0 ? color.red : color.green, text_size = size.small)
table.cell(_t, 1, 2, XLEindTextM12, text_color = XLEdiffM12 > 0 ? color.red : color.green, text_size = size.small)
table.cell(_t, 1, 3, XLUindTextM12, text_color = XLUdiffM12 > 0 ? color.red : color.green, text_size = size.small)
table.cell(_t, 1, 4, XLFindTextM12, text_color = XLFdiffM12 > 0 ? color.red : color.green, text_size = size.small)
table.cell(_t, 1, 5, XLIindTextM12, text_color = XLIdiffM12 > 0 ? color.red : color.green, text_size = size.small)
table.cell(_t, 1, 6, XLKindTextM12, text_color = XLKdiffM12 > 0 ? color.red : color.green, text_size = size.small)
table.cell(_t, 1, 7, XLVindTextM12, text_color = XLVdiffM12 > 0 ? color.red : color.green, text_size = size.small)
table.cell(_t, 1, 8, XLYindTextM12, text_color = XLYdiffM12 > 0 ? color.red : color.green, text_size = size.small)
table.cell(_t, 1, 9, XLREindTextM12, text_color = XLREdiffM12 > 0 ? color.red : color.green, text_size = size.small)
table.cell(_t, 1, 10, XLCindTextM12, text_color = XLCdiffM12 > 0 ? color.red : color.green, text_size = size.small)
```

Comment: Tables don't have the functionality to sort their contents directly. It would be best if you could provide compilable code so we can see how to manage your variables as they need to be inserted into arrays in order to be sorted.

Comment: Sure, I will edit my post to include full code. You'll have to excuse the messy code, I haven't removed lines that aren't being used and like I said, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table.cell` calls are fairly intensive, it's best to create the cells once, then modify them as needed.

When obtaining multiple values from the same ticker, it isn't necessary to use multiple security calls. There is a limit of 40 security calls and it is also an intensive operation. Multiple values can be obtained by using tuples ie :

`[a, b] = request.security(ticker, res, [a, b])`

With the sorting of values we first insert them in their existing order into arrays where the title, diff and perc values correspond by array index.

In this method we use a bubble sort using the perc array to determine the order. If a value needs to be moved, we also move the corresponding values from the diff and title array at the same time to maintain corresponding perc/diff/title values at the same position in the arrays.

````
//@version=5
indicator("Sector Relative Strength", overlay = true)

// Main logic

var _t = table.new (position.middle_left, 2, 12, frame_width = 5, border_width = 1)
var _t1 = table.new (position.bottom_right, 5, 2, frame_width = 2, border_width = 2)

// 6 month % momentum
[lastMonthmomo, sixMonthsclosemomo, twelveMonthsclosemomo] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", [ close, close [26], close [52] ])
diffM6momo = sixMonthsclosemomo - lastMonthmomo
indTextM6momo = "M6: " + str.tostring((lastMonthmomo - sixMonthsclosemomo)/sixMonthsclosemomo *100, format.percent)



// 12 months % momentum
diffM12momo = twelveMonthsclosemomo - lastMonthmomo
percM12momo = (lastMonthmomo - twelveMonthsclosemomo)/twelveMonthsclosemomo *100
indTextM12momo = "M12: " + str.tostring(percM12momo, format.percent)

// XLP %
[XLPlastMonth, twelveMonthsclose] = request.security("XLP", "W", [ close, close [52] ])
XLPdiffM12 = twelveMonthsclose - XLPlastMonth
XLPpercM12 = (XLPlastMonth - twelveMonthsclose)/twelveMonthsclose * 100

// XLB %
[XLBlastMonth, XLBtwelveMonthsclose] = request.security("XLB", "W", [ close, close [52] ])
XLBdiffM12 = XLBtwelveMonthsclose - XLBlastMonth
XLBpercM12 = (XLBlastMonth - XLBtwelveMonthsclose)/XLBtwelveMonthsclose * 100

// XLE %
[XLElastMonth, XLEtwelveMonthsclose] = request.security("XLE", "W", [ close, close [52] ])
XLEdiffM12 = XLEtwelveMonthsclose - XLElastMonth
XLEpercM12 = (XLElastMonth - XLEtwelveMonthsclose)/XLEtwelveMonthsclose * 100
 
// XLU %
[XLUlastMonth, XLUtwelveMonthsclose] = request.security("XLU", "W", [ close, close [52] ])
XLUdiffM12 = XLUtwelveMonthsclose - XLUlastMonth
XLUpercM12 = (XLUlastMonth - XLUtwelveMonthsclose)/XLUtwelveMonthsclose * 100

// XLF %
[XLFlastMonth, XLFtwelveMonthsclose] = request.security("XLF", "W", [ close, close [52] ])
XLFdiffM12 = XLFtwelveMonthsclose - XLFlastMonth
XLFpercM12 = (XLFlastMonth - XLFtwelveMonthsclose)/XLFtwelveMonthsclose * 100

// XLI %
[XLIlastMonth, XLItwelveMonthsclose] = request.security("XLI", "W", [ close, close [52] ])
XLIdiffM12 = XLItwelveMonthsclose - XLIlastMonth
XLIpercM12 = (XLIlastMonth - XLItwelveMonthsclose)/XLItwelveMonthsclose * 100

// XLK %
[XLKlastMonth, XLKtwelveMonthsclose] = request.security("XLK", "W", [ close, close [52] ])
XLKdiffM12 = XLKtwelveMonthsclose - XLKlastMonth
XLKpercM12 = (XLKlastMonth - XLKtwelveMonthsclose)/XLKtwelveMonthsclose * 100

// XLV %
[XLVlastMonth, XLVtwelveMonthsclose] = request.security("XLV", "W", [ close, close [52] ])
XLVdiffM12 = XLVtwelveMonthsclose - XLVlastMonth
XLVpercM12 = (XLVlastMonth - XLVtwelveMonthsclose)/XLVtwelveMonthsclose * 100

// XLY %
[XLYlastMonth, XLYtwelveMonthsclose] = request.security("XLY", "W", [ close, close [52] ])
XLYdiffM12 = XLYtwelveMonthsclose - XLYlastMonth
XLYpercM12 = (XLYlastMonth - XLYtwelveMonthsclose)/XLYtwelveMonthsclose * 100

// XLRE %
[XLRElastMonth, XLREtwelveMonthsclose] = request.security("XLRE", "W", [ close, close [52] ])
XLREdiffM12 = XLREtwelveMonthsclose - XLRElastMonth
XLREpercM12 = (XLRElastMonth - XLREtwelveMonthsclose)/XLREtwelveMonthsclose * 100

// XLC %
[XLClastMonth, XLCtwelveMonthsclose] = request.security("XLC", "W", [ close, close [52] ])
XLCdiffM12 = XLCtwelveMonthsclose - XLClastMonth
XLCpercM12 = (XLClastMonth - XLCtwelveMonthsclose)/XLCtwelveMonthsclose * 100

var string[] M12_titles = array.from("XLP M12: ", "XLB M12: ", "XLE M12: ", "XLU M12: ", "XLF M12: ", "XLI M12: ", "XLK M12: ", "XLV M12: ", "XLY M12: ", "XLRE M12: ", "XLC M12: ")
float[] M12_diff_vals = array.from(XLPdiffM12, XLBdiffM12, XLEdiffM12, XLUdiffM12, XLFdiffM12, XLIdiffM12, XLKdiffM12, XLVdiffM12, XLYdiffM12, XLREdiffM12, XLCdiffM12)
float[] M12_perc_vals = array.from(XLPpercM12, XLBpercM12, XLEpercM12, XLUpercM12, XLFpercM12, XLIpercM12, XLKpercM12, XLVpercM12, XLYpercM12, XLREpercM12, XLCpercM12)

f_linked_bubble_sort(_indexing_array, _linked_array1, _linked_array2) =>
    bool _change_found = true
    _i_array = array.copy(_indexing_array)
    _l_array1 = array.copy(_linked_array1)
    _l_array2 = array.copy(_linked_array2)
    _n = array.size(_i_array)
    if _n >= 2 and _n == array.size(_l_array1) and _n == array.size(_l_array2)
        while _change_found == true
            _changed = false
            for _i = 0 to _n - 2
                _i_val1 = array.get(_i_array, _i)
                _i_val2 = array.get(_i_array, _i + 1)
                _l1_val1 = array.get(_l_array1, _i)
                _l1_val2 = array.get(_l_array1, _i + 1)
                _l2_val1 = array.get(_l_array2, _i)
                _l2_val2 = array.get(_l_array2, _i + 1)       
                if _i_val1 < _i_val2
                    array.set(_i_array, _i, _i_val2)
                    array.set(_l_array1, _i, _l1_val2)
                    array.set(_l_array2, _i, _l2_val2)
                    array.set(_i_array,_i + 1, _i_val1)
                    array.set(_l_array1, _i + 1, _l1_val1)
                    array.set(_l_array2, _i + 1, _l2_val1)
                    _changed := true
            if _changed == false
                _change_found := false
    [_i_array, _l_array1, _l_array2]

[sorted_M12_perc_vals, sorted_M12_titles, sorted_M12_diff_vals] = f_linked_bubble_sort(M12_perc_vals, M12_titles, M12_diff_vals)

if barstate.isfirst
    for x = 0 to 1
        for y = 0 to 10
            table.cell(table_id = _t, column = x, row = y, text_size = size.small, text_color = color.blue)

if barstate.islast
    for y = 0 to 10
        title_text = array.get(sorted_M12_titles, y)
        perc_text = str.tostring(array.get(sorted_M12_perc_vals, y), format.percent)
        diff = array.get(sorted_M12_diff_vals, y)
        diff_color = diff > 0 ? color.red : color.green
        table.cell_set_text(table_id = _t, column = 0, row = y, text = title_text)
        table.cell_set_text(table_id = _t, column = 1, row = y, text = perc_text)
        table.cell_set_text_color(table_id = _t, column = 1, row = y, text_color = diff_color)```
````